# MultiSelect Component for VueJS

Tags: vuejs3

I am using the "Multiple Select Component" currently from JQuery. I just found out there is a Vue Version, but it adds a dependency to Jquery I do not like.

https://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/docs/en/introduction

Is there a native way to do this using VueJS 3.0 or any better replacement?

This is what I am going to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can either create a new component for the dropdown/checkboxes or use a similar component from Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#menu-props

For the new component, you could use somethig like this:

```
<div class="select">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="index" :value="option.value" v-model="selected">
      <label :for="index">{{ option.anything }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the codepen, I do not own the code.
https://codepen.io/huleos/pen/xQaYdK